# Missing Some Icons Cinnamon installed on Ubuntu 12.04.4

Tags: 12.04, themes, icons, cinnamon

I installed Cinnamon 2.0 and it is quite fast.  I had to install the Gnome Icons, which took care of most missing ICONS except for a few like Clementine.  This is always a problem with certain programs with Cinnamon going way back no matter if it installed with Ubuntu or via Mint.

Any ideas how to deal with this issue?  Is it a theme issue?  Can the issue be addressed with dconf or gconf?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:  This occurs only in the Menu and Taskbar.  The Clementine Icon shows up in the Sound Settings and Desktop.

Comment: I didn't realize that I had the same problem with the systray until I found this solution:

I edited /usr/share/cinnamon/applets/systray@cinnamon.org/applet.js and removed clementine from the hidden icons.

Unfortunately, this doesn't address the missing 'hidden icons' in the Menu.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [gnome-icon-theme-full [image: Install gnome-icon-theme-full]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-icon-theme-full) package:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-full
```